# Auto Map reference not found C#

Tags: c#, automapper

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    List<PackageDetailFile> pkgFiles = rdr.AutoMap <PackageDetailFile> ().ToList(); 
    foreach (PackageDetailFile pkgf in pkgFiles)
    {
         PackageDetail pkgd = getPackageDetail((long)pkgf.PackageDetailId);
    }
```

I have an error like:

> 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'AutoMap' and no extension method 'AutoMap' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and I can't find the AutoMap reference.

Comment: So, uh. Have you added a reference to AutoMap? Have you added a `using` in your code?

Comment: no i havent, because i couldnt find the reference .

Comment: Then maybe you should add the reference to your project?

Comment: i dont know how to add a reference

Comment: Where, then, did you find the code that includes `AutoMap`, a third party library to help map entity types to data storage? Maybe you should go back to that tutorial, and go through it properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is to add a reference to the `AutoMapper` library. How you do that, you can easily find out if you search. I'll help you on your way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.100).aspx has a rather full-length exhaustive how-to, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2157158/64976 is a more concise answer to a question about how to add references.

A more extended answer would perhaps be to suggest that you return to the basics of the `AutoMapper` documentation, .NET development and project structure and learn how to add a reference to a downloaded, third party assembly. http://automapper.org/ is a good place to start for information on `AutoMapper` itself.